# SublimeREPL Node.js: returns for every line?

Tags: javascript, node.js, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I'm a newb getting started with JavaScript.  I've been using SublimeText 2 and I was greatly helped in the past by using SublimeREPL to get immediate feedback when i was learning Ruby.

Now that I'm working on JS, I've tried to set it up for Node.  I installed Node.js on my computer, and it's working from the command line.  (However, I'd strongly prefer using SublimeREPL since I can run whole saved files from the color-coded text editor.)  SublimeREPL works pretty well, but I'm getting a strange 'undefined' return for *every line*. I'm not sure why, and I'd like it to stop.

For example, from this program:

```
var chhd = "cheese head"
var number = 0
while (number <= 12) {
    console.log(number);
    number = number + 2;
}
chhd.toUpperCase();
```

I get this result:

```
> undefined
> undefined
> ... ... ... 0
2
4
6
8
10
12
14
> 'CHEESE HEAD'
```

What's going on?  Should I be getting all these 'undefined's and elipses?  And if not, how can I remove them to get SublimeREPL for Node working properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about the ellipses, but the Node REPL behaves the same way on the 'undefined'.  The return value of the line in question (`var chhd = "cheese head";`) is in fact undefined when interpreted (insofar as it has no return value, like an equation would have (e.g. `1+2`).